# Domains have been verified, but Google still says app has not been verified

Tags: authentication, oauth

Message in the consent screen settings:

> Comply with domain verification requirements
> Ensure your application's domains have completed the Search Console verification process

But... all my domains on the search console have been verified. What can I do?

Comment: Have you met all of the property requirements shown in [the docs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en)?

When you have successfully filled Data should begin to appear in your property in a few days. 

What property type have you used? Can you please try another just to see if you are validating correctly?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? @Kevin Quinzel ?